# How to type updateQueryData in redux-toolkit

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit

I have implemented succesfully an optimistic update in redux-toolkit. But I am not able to type it correctly. My code is similar to the example of redux-toolkit.

```
const postsApiSlice = api.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getPost: builder.query<Post, number>({
      query: (id) => ROUTES.POST(id),
      providesTags: (result, error, id) => {
        return [{ type: POST_TAG, id }]
      },
    }),
    updatePostWithOptimism: builder.mutation<void, Pick<Post, 'id'> & Partial<Post>>({
      query: ({ id, ...patch }) => ({
        url: ROUTES.POST(id),
        method: 'PATCH',
        body: patch,
      }),
      async onQueryStarted({ id, ...patch }, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) {
        // ERROR at 'getPost': Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2345)
        const manualGetPostUpdate = dispatch(api.util.updateQueryData('getPost', id, (draft) => {
          Object.assign(draft, patch)
        }))
        try {
          await queryFulfilled
        } catch {
          manualGetPostUpdate.undo()
        }
      },
    }),
  }),
})
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The type of `api` does not know about the `getPost` endpoint. Use the injected api (`postsApiSlice.util.updateQueryData`) instead.

Also, on a sidenote: your api naming kinda indicates (I could be wrong) that you are adding that "injected" api into the `configureStore` call too as it's own slice. You don't need to do that - just adding `api` in `configureStore` is enough.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks! 
Im adding only the main api middleware (`getDefaultMiddleware().concat(api.middleware)`) to the `configureStore` :)